# Vectorization of outer product calculation

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `A` of size `KxN`. I want to take the outer product between each column of this matrix with itself, creating a new matrix of size `KxKxN`. I can do this iteratively by doing:

```
N = 5;
K = 3;

A = rand(K,N);

nA = zeros(K,K,N); 
for n=1:N
    nA(:,:,n) = nA(:,:,n) + A(:,n)*A(:,n)';
end
```

or faster by writing a mex-file (when `N` is large). However, I have not yet figured out if I can do this in a vectorized fashion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reshape your array to size `[K,1,N]` and `[1,K,N]` (i.e. inject singleton dimensions in the appropriate positions), you only need to multiply them using array broadcasting.

Newer versions of MATLAB with implicit broadcasting:

```
nA_bcast = reshape(A,[1,K,N]).*reshape(A,[K,1,N])
```

Older versions of MATLAB with the help of `bsxfun`:

```
nA_bsxfun = bsxfun(@times, reshape(A,[1,K,N]),reshape(A,[K,1,N]))
```

The three relevant arrays (i.e. `nA`, `nA_bcast` and `nA_bsxfun`) are all the same. Side note: `A'` will be the adjoint, you probably mean `A.'` for transpose.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer.

Comment: @Smajjk I'm glad it helped:) If the above indeed solves your problem, please consider marking my answer as accepted.